# Postgres materialized views with narrow permissions

Tags: postgresql

At my company we enforce very strict permissions on our Postgres database. Specifically, our applications that consume the database own nothing, and only have narrow CRUD permissions on the tables they need.

We are trying to begin using materialized views. However, in order to refresh a materialized view when the underlying data changes, an application would need ownership level access to the data. We are a bit skittish about this.

What I am wondering is if there are any alternatives? Maybe a special kind of trigger or something like that? Some way so that when an application writes to the underlying data, the materialized view is refreshed, without having to elevate the permissions of the application to the database.

Comment: Try the following. Wrap the refresh in a procedure (you will need dynamic sql) and specify `Security Definer` (BTW that is the default). Leave/set ownership of this function to the owner of the materialized view.  Finally `grant execute` of that procedure as necessary.